# .Net framework connection with Sybase DB with help of Entity framework

Tags: .net, database, frameworks, entity, sybase

Is sybase DB support entity framework with .net Framework 4.6.2 ?

sybase DB should connect  entity framework with .net Framework 4.6.2 ?